# ArcObjects - accessing layer data table from C#

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

I've spent all day yesterday trying to trace all errors but I'm just completely stuck now. Google isn't helpful either.

I'm trying to create a small C# tool which opens a MXD file in background and **reads** data from one of the datasets (layers). I can happily open the file, I can list all the layers inside with no problems. But no matter how hard I try, my **FeatureClass** or **DataTable** (tried both techniques) are always **null**.

I'm simply trying to get a reference to an ITable or IFeatureClass object to perform a **QueryFilter** on it.

**EDIT: Solution**

I really don't know why my approach using IMapDocument didn't work.  Documentation describes it as the *best* and *most efficient* way of accessing your data in background. The final solution involved creating an instance of ArcMap, creating a workspace and opening a feature class within it.

```
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
    m_application = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.MxDocumentClass().Parent;

    IWorkspace2 workspace = FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(@"F:\Projects\!Water\Sewers.gdb");

    IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;                  
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("Sewers_v5");
```

And

```
public IWorkspace2 FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(String path)
{        
    IObjectFactory objFactory = m_application as IObjectFactory;
    Type shpWkspFactType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");      
    string typeClsID = shpWkspFactType.GUID.ToString("B");
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)objFactory.Create(typeClsID);
    return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(path, 0) as IWorkspace2;
}
```

It's probably not the prettiest solution (made up from 5 different source codes) but it **works**.

I'm really disappointed by the ArcGIS documentation. So detailed and rich, and yet so useless.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your end purpose for looking at the table data, e.g are you looking to make selections, search for values, or get a collection of certain values for a certain field?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual values. I've got a nice QueryFilter set up to iterate through the results, that's not a problem. It's just getting that ITable or IFeatureClass object on which I can apply my query.

Comment: What does `ILayer.Valid` return?

Comment: False, which was worrying me from the start, but couldn't find any resources on how to make it valid.

Comment: Do you have arcmap?  If so, open and fix the mxd.  It might contain paths to datasets that are no longer valid.  Often checking "use relative paths" can simplify life.

Comment: Are you wanting to look within standalone table(s)?  IDisplayTable does this.

Comment: No no, everything works absolutely fine in ArcMap. All paths are correct and everything. the above is ALL the code I use. Could the problem be caused by me not initializing something else to begin with?

Comment: Guys, I've just solved it! After nearly 2 days and countless attempts. Editing my question to include the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "Background", do you mean a BackgroundWorker?  If so then you're running on an MTA thread.  Since ArcObjects expects to be running on an STA thread, this can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. By Background, I meant working without opening ArcMap user interface. So you interact only with my tool and don't even know that ArcMap does all the magic.

Comment: Was the original issue you reported occurring when running a BackgroundWorker? (Before taking the Arcmap approach).

Comment: Not at this stage. I've made the most basic WPF application just to implement this in a small environment before transferring across to the main tool. Tiny form, one button, click to connect and load. That's it. However if you have any tips on knows issues with implementing this in a multithreaded environment, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution**

Just to tag this question as answered, I'm reposting my working solution:

```
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
    m_application = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.MxDocumentClass().Parent;

    IWorkspace2 workspace = FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(@"F:\Projects\!Water\Sewers.gdb");

    IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;                  
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("Sewers_v5");
```

And

```
public IWorkspace2 FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(String path)
{        
    IObjectFactory objFactory = m_application as IObjectFactory;
    Type shpWkspFactType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");      
    string typeClsID = shpWkspFactType.GUID.ToString("B");
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)objFactory.Create(typeClsID);
    return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(path, 0) as IWorkspace2;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I can't accept my own answer for 2 days!. Is there a better way of tagging this question as answered so it doesn't clutter the board?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ILayer I've used IFeatureLayer within a cursor (ICursor) and IDataStatistics enumerating by System.Collections.IEnumerator to get values for a certain column.